# Add from CSV to array in for each loop

Tags: powershell

I have used import-csv to export a CSV to a variable called `ips`. I then have the for each loop below going through each item and adding it to an array with host name and IP address. The problem is when the command finishes I only have one array item but not the other items in the `ips` list.

```
foreach ($a in $ips){
    $a="$a"
    $a=$a.trimstart("@{")
    $a=$a.trimend("}")
    $a=[uri]$a
    $a=$a.authority
    $list=@{}
    $list.add($a,[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("$a").IPAddressToString)
}
```

Comment: Is '$list' the array that you are trying to populate?

Comment: put `$list=@{}` before the foreach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've declared your list inside the loop, so for each iteration, the list is re-instantiated.  Declare it outside the loop instead

Comment: apologies, didn't refresh the page before answering ... I see somebody has already answered

Comment: You can still delete your answer.